# Create Multiple Rows Carousel From Owl Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, owl-carousel

I am trying to insert an owl carousel in my web page. which contains the carousel items in multiple rows .

Right Now My Carousel Looks Something like this.

[image]

What I want to have is two more rwos inside it then the next & prev buttons. I tried the Following Code, ut its not working.

Here is My Code :

**HTML :**

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div><img class="client_image" src="assets/img/banner/download.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div><img class="client_image" src="assets/img/banner/download.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div><img class="client_image" src="assets/img/banner/download.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div><img class="client_image" src="assets/img/banner/download.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div><img class="client_image" src="assets/img/banner/download.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div><img class="client_image" src="assets/img/banner/download.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div><img class="client_image" src="assets/img/banner/download.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div><img class="client_image" src="assets/img/banner/download.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div><img class="client_image" src="assets/img/banner/download.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div><img class="client_image" src="assets/img/banner/download.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div><img class="client_image" src="assets/img/banner/download.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div><img class="client_image" src="assets/img/banner/download.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div><img class="client_image" src="assets/img/banner/download.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div><img class="client_image" src="assets/img/banner/download.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div><img class="client_image" src="assets/img/banner/download.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
</div>
```

Her is My **Javascript :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    nav: true,
  dots: false,
  loop: false,
  rewind: true,
  // autoWidth: true,
  stagePadding: 0,
  margin: 4,
  checkVisibility: true,
  navElement: 'div',
  responsive : {
    0 : {
      items: 4,
      slideBy: 4
    },
    768 : {
      items: 2,
      slideBy: 2
    },
    1024 : {
      items: 3,
      slideBy: 3
    },
    1280 : {
      items: 4,
      slideBy: 4
    },
    1440 : {
      items: 5,
      slideBy: 4
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: please create a working code snippet of the code

Comment: Maybe use pack of images instead of image, I mean wrap them in a parent with some css, then apply the carousel on those pack.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this :


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
      <div><img class="client_image" src="assets/img/banner/download.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div><img class="client_image" src="assets/img/banner/download.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div><img class="client_image" src="assets/img/banner/download.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div><img class="client_image" src="assets/img/banner/download.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div><img class="client_image" src="assets/img/banner/download.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
    </div> </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
      <div><img class="client_image" src="assets/img/banner/download.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div><img class="client_image" src="assets/img/banner/download.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div><img class="client_image" src="assets/img/banner/download.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div><img class="client_image" src="assets/img/banner/download.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div><img class="client_image" src="assets/img/banner/download.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
    </div></div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
      <div><img class="client_image" src="assets/img/banner/download.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div><img class="client_image" src="assets/img/banner/download.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div><img class="client_image" src="assets/img/banner/download.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div><img class="client_image" src="assets/img/banner/download.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div><img class="client_image" src="assets/img/banner/download.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
    </div>
    </div></div>
```